# How to modify a value in Pandas MultiIndex Dataframe with numeric values in location using index positions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas MultiIndex with numeric values for the index.

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                       'group2': [13, 18, 20, 77, 109, 123],
                       'value1': [1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                       'value2': [7.1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
                       })
df = df.set_index(['group1', 'group2'])

print df
```

The resultant dataframe looks like

```
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
1      13         1.1     7.1
       18         2.0     8.0
       20         3.0     9.0
2      77         4.0    10.0
       109        5.0    11.0
3      123        6.0    12.0
```

I want to access the value of the dataframe using the index.  For example the location '2'->'77'->value1 is 4.0.  How do I do this using the multiindex index values which would be 1 -> 0 -> value1.  The 1 is the second row in the first index.  The 0 is the first row in the second index.

Answer (score 4):

Using `.loc` and tuple of index `(2, 77)`

```
In [1487]: df.loc[(2, 77), 'value1']
Out[1487]: 4.0
```

Or, use `.query`

```
In [1488]: df.query('group1 == 2 and group2 == 77').value1
Out[1488]:
group1  group2
2       77        4.0
Name: value1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I want to query by the index location (like 1,0), not the index value.  Any idea how that would work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx[2,77],'value1'])
4.0
```

Also is possible use:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx[1,13:20],'value1'])
group1  group2
1       13        1.1
        18        2.0
        20        3.0
Name: value1, dtype: float64
```

Select by `iloc` in `MultiIndex` is not implemented yet - check [issue 7490](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7490).

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I want to query by the index location (like 1,0), not the index value.  Any idea how that would work?

Comment: I was afraid about it :( I try many things, but it is not implemented yet - check [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7490)